# Two SELECT Statements NESTED

Tags: python, tornado, psql

I have been trying to execute the following query, but it doesn't give me any output.

```
self.db.execute("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE patients.doctorid = (SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE username = '%s' % (usr)), callback=self.add_response)
```

I tried to execute the same query by hardcoding the values and it gives me the correct output.

```
select * from patients where patients.doctorid = (select id from doctors where username = 'admin');
```

Can someone tell whats the error?

Comment: Hi, could you check your first line of code. It has an opening quote (") but not a closing one.

Comment: if your inner query is returning more than one records then you should replace = by in

Comment: @BertRaeymaekers  I gave the code as below, but still doesnt work.
           self.db.execute("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE 
            patients.doctorid = (SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE 
             username = '%s' % (usr))", callback=self.add_response)

Comment: could you show us the snapshot of ``patients`` and ``doctors`` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute it like this:

```
 self.db.execute("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE patients.doctorid = (SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE username = '%s')" % (usr), callback=self.add_response)
```

I closed the SQL query with `"` and fixed the parentheses.

You can also try as shown [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters):

```
self.db.execute("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE patients.doctorid = (SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE username = '%s';", (usr), callback=self.add_response)
```